# Java Vertically Align Buttons

Tags: java, swing, layout

So here's my project: [image: Project]

So what I want to do is vertically align my color buttons while still having a horizontal-south border layout. I want to align two colors vertically. One top color then one bottom color. Then the next two colors will do the same thing next to it.

Comment: You could use BoxLayout, GridLayout, FlowLayout or a combination.

Comment: It would help if you showed your code

Answer (score 1):

> I want to align two colors vertically. One top color then one bottom color. Then the next two colors will do the same thing next to it.

Create a JPanel using a GridLayout, then add the buttons to the panel. Finallly add that panel to your panel that you add to the south:

```
JPanel buttons = new JPanel( new GridLayout(2, 0) );
buttons.add(redButton);
buttons.add(greenButton);
buttons.add(blueButton);
southPanel.add( buttons );
southPanel.add( clearButton );
```